# How does one start a process from CruiseControl .NET that persists after CC .NET exits?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have a program that normally runs constantly. Whenever there is a new checkin to Subversion, CC .NET kills the program and makes a new build. I want to start a new instance of the program from CC .NET.

Right now, if I use `<executable>`, then CC .NET hangs while it waits for the process to end, which will never come by definition.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to get CC.NET to launch something without it getting a return value and not have an exception. So to get around this my first thought would be to use the executable task to call some form of script, which can then launch the exe and return back to CruiseControl.